# Haskell Map function implementation issues

Tags: haskell, dictionary, compiler-errors, concatenation

I just began to learn Haskell and am having trouble with adjusting to the language, for example on the implementation of `map` more specifically when trying to do similar operations as in the example bellow;

```
rotate :: Dimensions ->  imgBlock -> [(imgBlock,Int)]
rotate d ((p, pix), s, t) 
  = zip [((p, f pix), s, t) | f <- transformate (fst d)] [0..7]

makeAllRotations :: Dimensions -> [imgBlock] -> [(imgBlock,Int)]
makeAllRotations d ib = map concat (rotate d ib)              //Error points Here
```

Where

```
type imgBlock = (Block, Int, Int)
type Block = (Pnt, Pxl)
type Dimensions = (Int, Int)
```

And this is one of the errors i get

```
asdf.hs:73:30:
    Couldn't match expected type `(imgBlock, Int)'
                with actual type `[a0]'
    Expected type: [[a0]] -> (imgBlock, Int)
      Actual type: [[a0]] -> [a0]
    In the first argument of `map', namely `concat'
    In the expression: map concat (rotate d ib)
```

I find myself quite frustrated trying to adjust to this new programming 'paradigm' where most of the things I managed to do are through trial and error. I am obviously not understanding `map` correctly, although i have read the documentation on this [website](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/map_f.html), but all the examples are shown in console like `map (2+) [1,2,3]` not so much when using them in functions.

Could I get some pointers on where am i going wrong on my `map` implementation. Thks

Comment: A good idea is to name intermediate values, use the `where` syntax and also give type signatures to everything. That forces you to think (opposed to trial and error). Do not lose hope on haskell! It'll repay you good if you are willing to adjust your thinking patterns. :)

Comment: I second @Tarrasch's suggestion. When learning Haskell, it helps enormously to give types to as many intermediate steps as necessary: if nothing else, it clarifies your thinking. Eventually you can omit more and more types and let the compiler infer them. Here instead of `map concat (rotate d ib)` if you'd written `map concat x where x :: …` and tried to reason through the type of x, you *may* have found the bug. Or else learn to interpret the error: it's saying that `concat` is of actual type `[[a0]] -> [a0]` (which you know) which cannot be matched with the type `[[a0]] -> (imgBlock, Int)`.

Comment: @Tarrasch, @ShreevatsaR; guys thanks so much for your advice and support, it really means the world in moments of frustration like these. I certainly put your suggestions in practice as obviously i need to find a way around getting used to declarative languages such as haskell. Once again thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to find the problem is to look at the types:

```
rotate :: Dimensions -> ImgBlock -> [(ImgBlock,Int)]
makeAllRotations :: Dimensions -> [ImgBlock] -> [(ImgBlock,Int)]
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
concat :: [[a]] -> [a]
```

The map function is trying to call concat on each of the (ImgBlock,Int) pairs in the list returned by rotate.  But concat expects to get a nested list as its argument.  But the big thing that helped me figure out how to fix it was looking at `rotate d ib`.  The second argument to rotate is ImgBlock, but in that context ib :: [ImgBlock].  You can't pass in a list when a single item is expected.  But that's what the map function is for.  It allows you to take a function that accepts a single item ('a' in the type signature above) and use that function when you have [a].  I suspect what you want is something like this:

```
makeAllRotations d ib = concat $ map (rotate d) ib
```

Because rotate returns a list, `map (rotate d) ib` returns a list of lists, which fits perfectly as the first argument to the concat function.

Comment: got it, i have to say i was not familiar with the `$` operator, but I guess i am now ;)

Comment: Concatenating the result of mapping a list-returning function over a list is common enough, that it has its own function `concatMap`:
`makeAllRotations d ib = concatMap (rotate d) ib`, or point-free: `makeAllRotations = concatMap . rotate`